# Passing Makefile variable to docker-compose is resulting in a "unknown shorthand flag" error

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, makefile, sh

I have a `Makefile` which I use to help our programmers get easily setup. At present I am writing one to pass an `IMAGE` tag to the docker-compose command, but I keep getting a `unknown shorthand flag` and I cant figure out why.

My `Makefile` is as follows;

```
.PHONY: all

ARCH = $(shell uname -m)

start:
    if [ "$(ARCH)" = "x86_64" ]; then \
        IMAGE_ARCH="amd64"; \
    elif [ "$(ARCH)" = "aarch64" ]; then \
        IMAGE_ARCH="arm64"; \
    else \
        echo "Unknown architecture: $(ARCH)"; \
    fi

    docker-compose up -d -e IMAGE=$IMAGE_ARCH
```

The error is;

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
```

Comment: Maybe try `make SHELL="sh -x"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose` has no `-e` option.

You can run this way :

```
.PHONY: all

ARCH := $(shell uname -m)

start:
    if [ "$(ARCH)" = "x86_64" ]; then \
        IMAGE_ARCH="amd64"; \
    elif [ "$(ARCH)" = "aarch64" ]; then \
        IMAGE_ARCH="arm64"; \ 
    else \   
        echo "Unknown architecture: $(ARCH)"; \
    fi; \ 
    IMAGE=$$IMAGE_ARCH docker-compose up -d
```

`docker-compose` command needs to be put in the same block as [`if`] in order to use $IMAGE_ARCH.